# YAML pipeline : How to disable a template depending on variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml pipeline calling a step AndroidSigning@3 which needs apksignerKeystoreFile input. I want to disable this step depending on a variable in the pipeline's library.
I get this error when starting the pipeline :

/build/pipelines/build-mobile-android.yml (Line: 42, Col: 14): Unexpected value 'ne(, 'release')'

Any help is appreciated

```
- group: variables-group

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
 - job: buil_app
   steps:
   - task: AndroidSigning@3
     enabled: ne(${{ variables.env }}, 'release')
     inputs:
       apkFiles: 'blabla'
       apksign: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at YAML schema reference it looks that this is not possible here

```
steps:
- script: string  # contents of the script to run
  displayName: string  # friendly name displayed in the UI
  name: string  # identifier for this step (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  workingDirectory: string  # initial working directory for the step
  failOnStderr: boolean  # if the script writes to stderr, should that be treated as the step failing?
  condition: string
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
  enabled: boolean  # whether to run this step; defaults to 'true'
```

`enabled` must be boolean. You may use `condition` and then `ne( variables['env'], 'release')` it should do the job.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work

/build/pipelines/build-mobile-android.yml (Line: 42, Col: 14): Unexpected value 'ne(variables['env'], 'release')'

Comment: Yeah. I tested this and it looks that you need to use condition here.

Comment: isn't ne(variables['env'], 'release') returns a boolean to 'enabled' ?

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
steps:
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  condition: eq(variables['env'], 'release') 
  displayName: AndroidSigning - enabled
  enabled: true
  inputs:
    apkFiles: 'blabla'
    apksign: true
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  condition: ne(variables['env'], 'release') 
  displayName: AndroidSigning - disable
  enabled: false
  inputs:
    apkFiles: 'blabla'
    apksign: true
```